# Simple where in sql

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a tables X and Y

Table X

```
a
b
c
d
```

Table Y

```
a 1   1
a 32  5
b 1   1
b 4   5
c 5   65
```

I want in output c and d, because they haven't in table Y record with value 1 1

How can I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't give any column names so I made some up!

```
SELECT col1
FROM tablex
EXCEPT
select col1
FROM tabley
WHERE col2=1 and col3=1
```

If you have oversimplified your example and actually need additional columns from `tablex` use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT tablex.*
FROM   tablex
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   tabley
                   WHERE  col2 = 1
                          AND col3 = 1
                          AND tablex.col1 = tabley.col1)
```

Comment: Using `EXISTS` will cause a scan for each record in tablex. The derived table should be faster.

Comment: @Matthew PK - In SQL Server `NOT EXISTS` will have exactly the same plan as `NOT IN` for NON NULLABLE columns but won't be vulnerable to (either semantic or performance) issues with NULLable columns hence my reason for preferring it. See http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/02/18/not-exists-vs-not-in/

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand:

```
SELECT X.column FROM X 
WHERE X.column NOT IN
(SELECT Y.column FROM Y WHERE Y.column2=1 AND Y.column3=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT col1
FROM TableX
WHERE col1 
NOT IN (select col1
FROM TableY
WHERE col2=1 and col3=1)
```